# Google Sheets not plotting (stacked column chart) all my series data

Tags: google-sheets, charts, stacked-chart, dynamic-chart-series

I began a Google Sheets stacked column chart that shows each Lister's daily sales. Sample:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTmrTQdJnTxik6tjHi5zsx-U6giCD-_Mwj0B1vv-bbE/edit?usp=sharing

gSheets is only plotting fifteen (15) out of sixty two (62) possible "series" data points. How do I get it to plot them all? Lister AN, for instance, should have more than two (2) stacked colors. In fact, AN should have eleven (11) displayed: 83058 [$19.79] below 83063 [$19.00] below 83083 [$49.99] below... 83121 [$6.97].

(1) Because of my data? I cannot think of a better way to organize it. Is there?

(2) Because of my setup?
__2a. I tried charting directly from the Base worksheet but gSheets needs the values to be tabled like Pivot1.
__2b. Of course, transposing the rows to columns makes no difference (see Pivot2).
__2c. I tried formatting the Sales Record Number (ColumnA) as plain text but that did nothing.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#stacked-column-charts) are coded solutions. I am only a novice. Though, if you have a good tutorial I can do that.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: I'm NOT saying that there isn't a limit to the number of series BUT I _have_ recreated a stacked column chart with 23 series. Rather than speculate on possible causes of why your chart is incomplete, please supply your data/spreadsheet.

Comment: If your range = A2:Z143, that's only 26 columns, less one (Sales Record Number) = 25 columns of data. Not sure how you get `sixty two (62) possible series` from 25 columns.

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text` [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz for feedback. I've edited so it includes a sample file. The sixty two possible "series" (gSheets term, not mine) are the data values to be plotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get it when generating a new chart and activating the [ Switch rows/columns ] **prior** to changing the format to a stacked column.

I tested this with my actual workbook, where the Listers are generated dynamically according to the day’s sales. It worked.

Problem solved.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Added the *[stacked chart in here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NTmrTQdJnTxik6tjHi5zsx-U6giCD-_Mwj0B1vv-bbE/edit#gid=1529101162)* for you to check out:

Your original chart doesnt seem to have full data range of the table linked and is causing this amiss.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rockinfreakshow. I cannot replicate your work with the original chart, even when the Setup specs are the same: (Data range: A2:P1000; Switch rows/columns: true; Use column A as headers: true; Use row 2 as labels: true) I can replicate it when I generate a new chart and activate the [ Switch column/rows ] **prior** to changing the format to a stacked column.

Comment: Any specific reason you have to fix the old(existing) chart & not go ahead to create a new one that meets the needs?!

Comment: No specific reason to preserve the old chart. The solution, however, isn’t intuitive. Even when generating a new chart, I change the format first to [stacked column]. I then proceed at the top of the Chart Editor and work my way down. I assume most users will do the same and end up similarly frustrated. I dare say it’s a design flaw because those checkmarks would probably be better suited immediately underneath Data Range. I’ll submit my recommendation to Google. In the meantime, I take your point: (in gSheets at least) start afresh, work broadly toward a solution instead of in reverse.